# Chronic "ERR_NETWORK_CHANGE" on AT&T Motivate

Tags: mobile-data, internet, dns

My Android phone was recognized as a V-Smart Hobson when I activated it. My Google Account *also* said the same under "My Device". This error has become so chronic, it is part of every single connection now. This is an AT&T Motivate Android phone that I discovered is exclusive to AT&T (it has several odd design features already anyway). But when my 1st Google Account recognized this as a V-Smart Hobson rather than a Motivate, a quick search says a V-Smart Hobson is a hub for TIOT type devices.

My Google account was hacked on 2nd day. So I made a new account, now says this is an *unrecognized* V-Smart. These chronic errors then began. Also chronic CAPTCHAs. I've several sites denying me access, saying that "Bots not allowed". I found a site that helped me flush my DNS, but when I tried to change to a private DNS, it just goes back to automatic DNS.

IDK, but this is eating data like Pacman dots while I'm connecting and getting nowhere. I have $75 prepay & I'm out of data in 8 days for this 2nd month again.

Comment: Sounds like your device is infected with malware. Perform a factory reset and restart with a fresh phone. And this time only install those apps you really need and only from Google Play Store.

Comment: I agree. I only have Avast Mobile, a VPN & 2nd Line all thru Play Store but this Prepay DID SWAP SSID WiFi MID-ACTIVATION! The IMEI & ICCID both on the screen & the new number JUST popped up. I had no choice but to allow it to finish activation. I believe it was hacked B4 I even added the 1st Google Account. This whole issue with this prepaid, made me realize TracFone used to give enuf data to activate securely & Providers need to offer prepaid customers the same secure activation a contract customer has. I will take your advice, & see if my warrenty will replace this phone too! 